# CQRS/Event Sourcing, how to get consistent data to apply business rules?

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs, event-sourcing

at times I'm developing a small project using CQRS pattern and Event Sourcing.
I have a structural issue and I'm not aware of which solution to take to resolve it.

Imagine the following example:
A command is sent with information that a client of the bank had deposited some amount of money (DepositCommand).
In the command handler/Entity/Aggregate (which is not important for the discussion) a business rule has to be applied;
If the client is one of the top 10% with more money in the account win some prize.

The question is how can I get up-to-date, consistent, data to know if the client after its deposit is in the top 10%?

- I can't use the event store because is not possible to make such a query;
- I'm not sure if I can use the read model because is not 100%
  sure that is up to date.

How do you do, in cases where you need data from a database to apply a business rule? If I don't pay attention to up-to-date data I run into possibilities
of giving the prize to two different clients

Looking forward to hearing your opinion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Any information that an aggregate requires to make business decisions should be stored as a part of the aggregate's state. As such, when a command is received to deposit money in to a client's account, you should already have the current/update state for that client which can contain the current balance for each of their accounts.

I would also suggest that an aggregate should never go to the read-model to pull information. Depending on what you are trying to achieve, you may enrich the command with additional details from the read model (where state is not critical), but the aggregate itself should be pulling from it's own known state.

---

**EDIT**

After re-reading the question, I realize you are talking about tracking state across multiple aggregates. This falls in the realm of a saga. You can create a saga that tracks the threshold required to be in the top 10%. Thus, whenever a client makes a deposit, the saga can track where this places them in the ranking. If that client crosses over the threadshold, you can then publish a command from the saga to indicate that they meet the criteria required.

In your case, your saga might track the total amount of all deposits so when a deposit is made, a decision can be made as to whether or not the client is now in the top 10%. Other questions you may want to ask yourself... if the client deposits $X amount of money, and immediately widthrawls $Y to drop back under the threashold; what should happen? Etc.

---

Very crude aggregate/saga handle methods...

```
public class Client : Aggregate
{
    public void Handle(DepositMoney command)
    {
        // What if the account is not known? Has insufficient funds? Is locked? etc...
        // Track the minimum amount of state required to make whatever choice is required.
        var account = State.Accounts[command.AccountId]; 

        // Balance here would reflect a point in time, and should not be directly persisted to the read model;
        // use an atomic update to increment the balance for the read-model in your denormalizer.
        Raise(new MoneyDeposited { Amount = command.Amount, Balance = account.Balance + command.Amount }); 
    }

    public void Handle(ElevateClientStatus command)
    {
        // you are now a VIP... raise event to update state accordingly...
    }
}

public class TopClientSaga : Saga
{
    public void Handle(MoneyDeposited e)
    {
        // Increment the total deposits... sagas need to be thread-safe (i.e., locked while state is changing).
        State.TotalDeposits += e.Amount;

        //TODO: Check if client is already a VIP; if yes, nothing needs to happen...

        // Depositing money itself changes the 10% threshold; what happens to clients that are no longer in the top 10%?
        if (e.Balance > State.TotalDeposits * 0.10)
        {
            // you are a top 10% client... publish some command to do whatever needs to be done.
            Publish(new ElevateClientStatus { ClientId = e.ClientId, ... });
        }
    }

    // handle withdrawls, money tranfers etc?
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply Calgary, you got my point. I have to read more about Saga pattern and then I reply with a formed opinion.

Comment: so you are sugesting that i have a saga that is created and disposed with the application, like a singleton. that saga track the total ammount of deposited money. each client that deposit money add that ammount to the saga total ammount. to store the total ammount i use the event store? i asking because when i launch the application i need to load the current total ammount. this makes sense? thanks

Comment: @JP - The saga will manage it's own state. At some point you will create a `Branch` or a `Bank` which may start the saga to track total deposits. Whenever a deposit or other related event is made, the saga state would be retrieved (ideally cached in memory), such that it always knows the running total. If your application needs to know the total for other reasons, then perhaps the total becomes a property of the `bank` or `branch` aggregate state. Your aggregates/sagas are the authority on all data, you don't want to go to the read-model for this type of information. Make sense?

Comment: What you have said is completely right. i only want to be sure that you are thinking that this saga has a singleton lifetime. imho i think that total should be stored for system recovery. that leads me to think if saga data/state should be stored in the event store

Comment: @JP - Yes, the saga state does need to be persisted to the db after each event is processed (similar to commits). I would keep a copy cached in memory to save the cost of reloading between events as well. In your case you may have only one instance, but I would not refer to the saga as a singleton. The saga will start with some event (i.e., BranchOpened) and will live as long as required until explicitly completed (perhaps BranchClosed). Often you could have multiple instances of the same saga running with different correlation ids (i.e., BranchA's top clients and BranchB's top clients).